# Why "Could not insert single-step breakpoint at"?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I compiled a debugging version program using gcc for arm. I debug it using gdb7.3. I can set normal break points, but I can't execute "next" command. It prompt "Could not insert single-step breakpoint at 0x?????".
If you need more detail information, I will append it.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting breakpoints in C++ constructors? Can you post `info breakpoints` output?

Comment: The root cause is that I compiled the program with the arm thumb option. Can't the thumb instruction be debugged?